# Oracle Forms and Reports

Tags: oracleforms

I would like to know the **future(as in my personal growth) of `Oracle Forms and reports developer`**. And will learning this be helpful in learning any other technology.Thanks in Advance!

P.S:-I am a Fresher and I would like to know the advantage of learning Oracle Forms!!!Guidance Required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest versions of Oracle Forms are very good for fast input through a web application. Other web applications build in for example Oracle ADF, Apex, Asp, Php you can't give fast input. If you want to build applications for client server or just for a desktop you can use other programming languages like .net

The problem with Oracle Forms at the moment is that Oracle has mentioned that it won't be supported in the future. In the meanwhile they have come back to this and they still support it for the moment and in the near future. But they won't put much effort in supporting new features in the future.
So if you want a fancy application with lots of new gadgets and so on you are wrong by choosing Oracle Forms.

Comment: What your source for "Oracle has mentioned that it won't be supported in the future"? From the Oracle Forms page on Oracle Technology Network it states (and has done for as long as I can remember) "Oracle remains committed to the development of this technology, and to the ongoing release as a component of the Oracle platform." http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/overview/index-098877.html

Comment: At this moment it is not on an official site anymore. But they have stated this in many channels a while ago, many company's started to find a solution for all there webforms to change it to another technology. Because Oracle got a lot of bad feedback for this statement they changed there view.

Comment: It's a myth that you answer only serves to perpetuate. Oracle have never said that Oracle Forms will be de-supported. If this has been "stated in many channels" then quote one. It won't be difficult to find a archived copy.